# Filter function in nonogram solver

Tags: function, haskell, lambda, filter, higher-order-functions

I have to understand the Deductive solver By Ted Yin from https://wiki.haskell.org/Nonogram

i don't know how

```
elim b w ps = filter (\p -> all (\x -> x `elem` p) b &&
                            all (\x -> x `notElem` p) w) ps
```

works. I only know that

```
all (\x -> x `notElem` [1]) [1,2,3,4]
```

gives `False`, and

```
all (\x -> x `elem` [1]) [1,1,1,1]
```

gives `True`.

but i don't know hot to run all `elim` function and how it works

Comment: What exactly you do not understand here?

Comment: I can't put any example argument to make it works

Comment: did you derive what the type is of `elim`?

Comment: You're most of the way there. You have `filter (\p -> <known> && <known>) ps`. Do you know what `filter` does?

Comment: yes,   :: (Eq a, Foldable t, Foldable t1, Foldable t2) =>
     t a -> t1 a -> [t2 a] -> [t2 a]

Comment: yes, i think i quite know how filter work, but i don't understand how it works with (True) or (False)

Comment: For clarity you could also say `:: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]`

Comment: oh @DarthFennec its a good hint

Comment: "yes, i think i quite know how filter work, but i don't understand how it works with (True) or (False)" I'm not sure what you're confused about. `filter` takes a function that returns a `True` or `False`, that's how it knows what to filter. You have an expression that is `True` iff everything in `b` is in `p`, and you have an expression that is `True` iff nothing in `w` is in `p`. You're filtering out `p`s that don't pass both of these tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, help yourself to a little whitespace to aid understanding, and name your subexpressions:

```
elim b w ps = filter (\p -> all (\x -> x `elem`    p) b  &&
                            all (\x -> x `notElem` p) w
                       ) ps

            = filter foo ps
                where
                   foo p =  all (\x -> x `elem`    p) b  &&
                            all (\x -> x `notElem` p) w

            = filter foo ps
                where
                   foo p =  all tst1 b  &&  all tst2 w
                      where
                         tst1 = (\x -> x `elem`    p)
                         tst2 = (\x -> x `notElem` p)

            = filter foo ps
                where
                   foo p =  (&&)  (all tst1 b)  (all tst2 w)
                      where
                         tst1 x = elem    x p
                         tst2 y = notElem y p
```

Now what does that do? Or better yet, what is it? Let's go by some types to build up our insight here:

```
filter :: (a ->                Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
foo    ::  a ->                Bool
ps     ::                               [a]
filter    foo                           ps  :: [a]
p      ::  a
foo        p                :: Bool
(&&)        :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
all tst1 b  :: Bool
all tst2 w  ::         Bool
---------------------------
all  :: (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> Bool
tst1 ::  t -> Bool
tst2 ::  t -> Bool
b    ::                [t]
w    ::                [t]
---------------------------
......
---------------------------
elim             b      w               ps  :: [a]
elim ::         [t] -> [t] ->           [a] -> [a]
```

Complete the picture by working through the types of `tst1` and `tst2` to find out the relationship between the `t` and `a` types.

---

```
tst1    ::         t        -> Bool          -- tst1 x = elem    x p
tst2    ::         t        -> Bool          -- tst2 y = notElem y p
x       ::         t
y       ::         t
elem    :: Eq t => t -> [t] -> Bool
notElem :: Eq t => t -> [t] -> Bool
p       ::              [t]                  -- it was : a !
```

Thus `a ~ [t]` and `[a] ~ [[t]]` and finally,

```
elim             b      w               ps  :: [[t]]
elim :: Eq t => [t] -> [t] ->         [[t]] -> [[t]]
```

So then `filter foo` leaves only those `p`s in `ps` for which `foo p == True`.

And that means `all tst1 b == True` *and*  `all tst2 w == True`.

And that means, every `x` in `b` is an element of `p`, and every `y` in `w` is *not* an element in `p`. Or in other words only such `p`s in `ps` are left alone in the resulting list for which

```
foo p =  (b \\ p) == []   &&   (p \\ w) == p
```

holds:

```
import Data.List (\\)

elim b w ps = [ p | p <- ps, (b \\ p) == [], (p \\ w) == p ]
```